# Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImageView' to parameter of type 'UIImage*' (xcode5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I get a error in this code line:

```
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_imagView];
```

And this is the error:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImageView' to parameter of type 'UIImage*'
```

Does somebody know what I have to do?

Comment: isn't that really obvious ? Your method takes a parameter of type  `UIImage *` but you're sending an image view.  [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_imagView.image]; would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

Passing argument of UIImageView instead of UIImage

## Solution

Change code back to :

```
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_imagView.image];
```

Comment: Wouldn't worry about it. (Got someone who dislikes you here?)

Comment: I am here to learn and to share my abilities that I have on programming, so I am happy if I get a down vote and explains why so I could improve my answer and also my knowledge. Anyway thnx for you advice, I'll give the one vote up for your answer who somebody took it without having any idea! @StevenFisher :)

Comment: Ditto. Unless what I say is obviously wrong, and yours looks right to me. Only issue I see is the typo, and that's in the question, too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Background:

A **UIImageView** is used to display a **UIImage** in the view hierarchy. The UIImage is the image; the UIImageView is what draws it, so it includes its position on the view controller, how to stretch it, z-order, alpha, etc. There are other ways to display an image which you might use if you're writing your own UIView subclass.

Immediate problem:

A UIImageView is not a UIImage. A UIImageView *has* a UIImage, though, so you can just use this:

```
GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:_imageView.image];
```